# Weird behavior of Garbage Collector Android

Tags: android, memory-management, garbage-collection

For application, that I'm working on efficiency is very important. In order, to avoid unnecessary garbage collection, I allocated a lot of memory(in order to grow heap size) and  released it right away. However, no matter how much free memory I have, Garbage collection still occurs.

When I don't do this extra memory allocation/releasing, I have only 24% of free memory, compared to 63% in log below, but amount of GC invocations is the same. GC pauses are the same. Execution time(of Program) is the same.

Can anyone explain, this weird GC behavior? Why `GC_FOR_ALLOC` is triggered at all? There is ton of free memory.

In my program main operations are: file reading, encryption, data transmission.
For data transmission and File reading, I use `ByteBuffer` and `FileChannel`, `SocketChannel`.
Can huge amount of ByteBuffer allocations be a bottleneck? 
Seems like I don't have any memory leaks as well.

Program tested on GalaxyS3 (Android 4.4.2) and GalaxyS2 (Android 4.1.2)

```
12-21 00:30:54.973: I/dalvikvm-heap(30222): Grow heap (frag case) to 44.361MB for 25000016-byte     allocation
12-21 00:30:55.463: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 8% free 42893K/46416K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
12-21 00:31:01.900: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28367K, 63% free 18615K/49480K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
12-21 00:31:07.606: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3600K, 63% free 18648K/49480K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
12-21 00:31:12.151: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3640K, 63% free 18652K/49480K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
12-21 00:31:17.757: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3627K, 63% free 18669K/49480K, paused 93ms, total 93ms
12-21 00:31:24.014: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3641K, 63% free 18679K/49480K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
12-21 00:31:30.090: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3644K, 63% free 18688K/49480K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
12-21 00:31:35.536: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3639K, 63% free 18706K/49480K, paused 50ms, total 50ms
12-21 00:31:41.763: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3659K, 63% free 18711K/49480K, paused 52ms, total 53ms
12-21 00:31:47.439: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3652K, 63% free 18724K/49480K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
12-21 00:31:53.085: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3677K, 63% free 18716K/49480K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
12-21 00:31:59.882: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3672K, 63% free 18711K/49480K, paused 50ms, total 67ms
12-21 00:32:05.838: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3672K, 63% free 18704K/49480K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
12-21 00:32:13.276: D/dalvikvm(30222): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3680K, 63% free 18686K/49480K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
```

P.S. Code is very long, thus I can't post it.

Thank you for any help, hint or guess.

Comment: It's not garbage collection that's weird here; it's your application's behavior

Comment: @AndrewBarber What is wrong with application's behavior? Why it is not GC?

Comment: Your first paragraph. That's not how an application will generally behave. You also don't seem to understand how garbage collection works, or why. Free memory isn't as important as you think it is.

Comment: @AndrewBarber. But with this amount of free memory GC_CONCURRENT should be triggered. And it should be faster, than GC_FOR_ALLOC.

Comment: Its not the gc, its your app.  You're allocating way too many objects, most likely a lot of small objects.  Java can be really bad with that.  What are you doing at the time you're seeing this?

Comment: After rereading-  allocating and freeing memory is what causes this.  The best thing to do is allocate and reuse at an object level.  By the way allocating a huge chunk of memory and then releasing it will grow the app's heap, but not in a good way. The memory that was allocated will still be allocated until the GC runs.  So that newly claimed memory can't actually be reused.  That means your algorithm will be requesting even more memory to get free memory.  This is particularly bad if you didn't actually request enough to grow the heap, but it was actually filled from pre-allocated memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why GC_FOR_ALLOC is triggered at all? There is ton of free memory.

Quoting [myself](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html):

> the JVM has one thing that the Dalvik VM does not: a compacting garbage collector.
>
> When we write programs in a language running on a runtime supporting garbage collection, we create a bunch of objects, and we later release some subset of those objects. The other ones we hold onto for a while, because we are still using them. In Android, for example, our `Application`, our `ContentProviders`, our `Threads`, our own static data members, and so on are going to live for quite some time, in many cases for the duration of the process. Anything they can reach also will not get garbage-collected. So, we allocate a bunch of memory and release some of that memory as our app runs.
>
> With a compacting garbage collector, the long-lived objects get slid around in memory, to allow the freed-up blocks of memory to be coalesced. The net is that all free heap space should be available as one contiguous block, eligible for allocation.
>
> (the details are more complicated than that, but this is a blog post, not a dissertation)
>
> With a non-compacting garbage collector, nothing is slid around in memory. We wind up with heap fragmentation, as what was once a pristine 16MB (or 32MB, or 48MB, or whatever) heap now is a bunch of objects with interspersed free memory. Even though we might have 10MB of free heap space, if the largest single block of that free heap space is only 1MB, we cannot allocate an 8MB Bitmap, because there is no free block big enough.
>
> The Dalvik VM has a non-compacting garbage collector.

Your `GC_FOR_ALLOC` lines suggest that you are making allocations for which there is no free contiguous big-enough block at the time of the allocation, forcing Dalvik to have to go through GC to try to free up memory such that you wind up with a big-enough block.

If you want to reduce or remove your `GC_FOR_ALLOC` lines, you are going to need to try to determine what your big allocations are. Here, "big" refers to individual allocations, so a highly complex object graph might be "big" overall, but each individual object is small, and therefore isn't an issue. `byte[]` allocations tend to be the culprits, at least for bitmap-wrangling apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. In my implementation I do allocate a huge amount of small objects. Probably, they're messing up heap